# ProjectTypeGuid is removed on load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, csproj

I am loading an already checked in MVC project.

The .csproj file has the following projecttypeguids :

```
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47};{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

But, when I load the project on my VS, the Projecttypeguids is getting updated to the following:

```
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
```

On looking in the internet, I found that the guid that is removed corresponds to MVC4. 
I am not sure why the GUID is being removed when I load the project. Also, I do have MVC4 installed. When I created a new MVC4 Project, I see the GUID appear in that new project.

Anything I am missing here ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you loading your project in a newer version of Visual Studio?

Comment: No, it was the same version that it was developed in. VS 2012. But, I do have VS 2013 installed on the same machine.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with VS2013. I thought, there is some package that is doing it. So I uninstalled all the packages but no luck. I then formatted the laptop, and had a fresh VS2013 installation, but it still removes the Guid.

Comment: I'm having this issue because I started the application in VS2013, but now I need to continue in VS2012. It still opens and runs in VS2012 but I get this issue when I try to put the {E3E379DF-F4C6-4180-9B81-6769533ABE47} guid in my csproj file. When I reopen it's removed.